# Using bootstrap + d3.js. Bar graph not showing up

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-chevron-left vertical-center"></i></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="row">
                <p>Name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <center>
                    <div id="chart"></div>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-chevron-right vertical-center"></i></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**d3.js**

```
        var dataObj = []

        for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            dataObj[i] = {
                potenial: 5 + i,
                actual: 12 + (2 * i),
                latest: 9 + (i)
            }
        }

        console.log(dataObj)

        // Create variable for the SVG
        var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
                .attr("height",'100%')
                .attr("width",'100%');

        // Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to rectangles for bar chart
        svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(dataObj)
            .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("height", function(d, i) {return (d.actual * 10)})
                .attr("width","60")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 80) + 25})
                .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 400 - (d.actual * 10)});
```

**Style**

```
<style>

    .vertical-center {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    .container-fluid {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .row {
        height: 100%;
    }
    i {
        color: silver;
    }
    i:hover {
        color: #333;
    }
</style>
```

I am using both bootstrap and d3.js to add a window that displays an overlay bar-graph. When I try to load this, the chart doesn't appear. But when I inspect the element, it exists.

[image]

It's weird because when I tried to use it without bootstrap, it showed up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Construct a running code snippet `<>` toolbar button

Comment: try and give your chart some real width and height and not x%, why don't you use scales for x and y calculation, makes it independent of the size of the svg.

Comment: @rioV8 Why do we have to use an actual value, not a percentage? What I eventually want to do is, I want the chart to fully fill the div that is wrapping up the chart.

Comment: sometimes using % the svg gets a size of 0x0 depending on the tools is used. if the svg has a size you can determine in the code it is OK. Looking again at your screen shot it looks like you do not define a fill and/or stroke for the rects in CSS or set as attribute. by hard coding your sizes you assume you have at least MxN size svg. Better to use scales.

Comment: for some reason SO comments do not want me to add at-sign Dawn17

Comment: @Dawn17 If you want the chart to fill the div, why not get the dimensions of the div and assign it to the chart? If you're using jQuery you can get dimensions by ```$("#div").width()``` and ```$("#div").height()```
Or d3: ```d3.select("#div").node.getBBox()["width"]```